# Restore in app purchase not finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I use following codes to start restoring In App Purchase:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
SKReceiptRefreshRequest * request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

app store procedure starts and this method from SKTransactionObserver is called:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

But this method is never called to finish transaction:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
Updating xCode from 5.1 to 5.1.1 was the reason. Apple is going to have a little changes in it's in app purchase methods. And it forces developers to make those changes in latest version of xCode.

by the way I modified my methods like this:

restore request:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) {
    SKReceiptRefreshRequest * request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
[self registerAsPurchaseObserver];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

and responses goes to:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [Delegate transactionDidFail];
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if (receipt) {
        [Delegate transactionDidRestorePurchaseSuccessfullyWithReciept:receipt];
    }
    else{
        [Delegate transactionDidFail];
    }
}
```